# Simple JQuery Logic

Tags: jquery

I think I wrote myself into a corner and don't know quite how to back up. I really just need to make each div close separately onclick as well as the close all option.

http://jsfiddle.net/7U9QY/4/

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('.bar').click(function() {
        $('.full').toggle(600);
    });

});
```

Comment: what do you want to do with a[href*=#]:not([href=#])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CKWm3/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $('.bar').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('a').next().next().toggle(600);
    });
});
```

---

Find the closest `a` tag than find the `next next` element and `toggle`

---

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: I wish I understood the .next .next vs div:first difference. Thank you guys. If I want to make it CLOSE ALL too ... what should I do?

Comment: @user3299992 to Collapse all use `$('.full').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple,  you need to have a relative selector where you're toggling your full class element. It would be better if your parent div had some sort of selectable attribute / class, but for now it just happens that the first parent div satisfies the relative selector to target the .full div next to the bar

```
$('.full', $(this).parents('div:first')).toggle(600);
```

You can see the working solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/7U9QY/5/